# SRID and Name relationship

Tags: coordinate-system, srid

PostGIS comes with a table of spatial reference systems with each one being identitfied by a SRID. However, from a user's perspective, SRID is just a number and doesn't tell them much. Is there a resource that associates SRID with  more descriptive names?

Comment: ...the `srtext` column of said table holds the OGC WKT representation with the standardized details of each CRS.

Comment: Thanks! I had looked at that column initially and thought it had too much info. But upon looking at it again, I realize that I can just parse the text and extract the parts I need. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want/need to have more info from within *PostGIS*, running something like

```
SELECT  srid,
        left(split_part(srtext, '"', 1), -1) AS "type",
        split_part(srtext, '"', 2) AS "name",
        split_part((regexp_split_to_array(srtext, 'UNIT\[\"'))[array_length(regexp_split_to_array(srtext, 'UNIT\[\"'), 1)], '"', 1) AS units
FROM    spatial_ref_sys
WHERE   srid IN (4326, 32632);
```

results in

```
 srid  |  type  |         name          | units  
-------+--------+-----------------------+--------
  4326 | GEOGCS | WGS 84                | degree
 32632 | PROJCS | WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N | metre
```

*I never wanted to learn regexp logic any better than this. Obviously, you could scan the whole WKT string for anything you need to know. And improve on the above, especially the `units` expression...*

---

Alternatively, query the `spatial_ref_sys.srtext` or `spatial_ref_sys.proj4text` columns to get either the whole *OGC* WKT representation or the *proj4* definition of each SRID.

Answer (score 8):

A good modern web resource is [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/)

It's "modern" because it has been synchronized to recent versions of the EPSG reference database, as stated at the bottom of the web page. It's source is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io).

It's also pretty easy to use. For example, SRID=4326, here is the description web page and links to various formats:

- http://epsg.io/4326
- http://epsg.io/4326.wkt
- http://epsg.io/4326.esriwkt
- http://epsg.io/4326.gml
- http://epsg.io/4326.proj4
- http://epsg.io/4326.sql

Answer (score 5):

I use http://spatialreference.org and  http://www.epsg-registry.org.

spatialreference.org has the spatial reference information in numerous formats:

[image]

And EPSG has an access database you download:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that spatialreference.org was last updated in 2013, and was made from an older/outdated version of the EPSG database. The webpage was abandoned, and there are no plans to update it.

Comment: Didn't realise that. Who owns the domain and runs the site?

Comment: @JayCummins see [about](http://spatialreference.org/about/) for who set it up. They are excellent folks in the opensource geospatial community, and are happy for anyone to [take the keys and catch up to the modern world](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/finding-proj-descriptions-tt5381989.html#a5382460)